# Getting the python path set up properly scrapy/django

Tags: python, django, scrapy

I have a scrapy project that I put it inside a Django project root folder.

And I have these lines added to the setting :

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.append('/home/user/Django-projects/first_project')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'first_project.settings'
```

Now when I try to import a model in items.py :

```
from blog.models import Annonce
```

I get this message :

```
ImportError: No module named blog.models
```

Django project directory:
.

```
├── assets
│   ├── logo.jpg
│   └── screen.png
├── blog
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin.pyc
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── forms.pyc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── database.sql
├── first_project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── wsgi.pyc
├── manage.py
├── scrapy project
│   ├── marocannonces
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── items.py
│   │   ├── items.pyc
│   │   ├── middlewares.py
│   │   ├── middlewares.pyc
│   │   ├── pipelines.py
│   │   ├── pipelines.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── settings.pyc
│   │   └── spiders
│   │        └── some spiders here...
│   ├── scrapy.cfg
└── templates
    └── blog
        ├── contact.html
        ├── home.html
        └── read.html
```

How can I fix this please ?

Comment: Do you have a directory named blog with a models.py file? Might be helpful to post more information. Directory structure, full items.py code, etc.

Comment: OKay I added the directory tree. Thanks